# Proper way to include special developer/testing features in iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, testing, app-store-connect

I am building an iPhone app for a client who will ultimately have control over some dynamic content that appears in the app and sending push notifications to the user base. I would like my client to have a special version of the app, or special features enabled in his own installation of the app, so he can test some of the content he pushes before rolling it out to the public. What is the correct way to do this? I would like it to be sustainable such that I don't have to manually provision his phone in person every time I release an update, or whenever he may get a new phone in the future. The app does not authenticate users, so there's no pre-existing infrastructure for determining the identity of a particular user.

My only idea, which seems like a bad one, is essentially to include an "easter egg" where you tap in a certain combination on the app's tab bar or something crazy like that, after which the extra features would be enabled. But surely there's a less hackish way of doing this?

Comment: How about test flight? While it does require you to manually enter the email addresses of the people who would use the app before release, you don't need to do profile provisioning.
Just a thought...

Comment: @TooManyEduardos I was hoping TestFlight would be a solution, but I haven't used it before so I don't know what all I can do with it. My use case isn't for someone to test the app before it's released, it's for someone to have special admin features within the app, even after release. Is that a good use case for TestFlight?

Comment: No, it would be a tough one then. TestFlight is for unreleased versions and it only lasts 30 days. You can extends the time by uploading a new build (and not release it), but you'll be doing that every 30 days. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `UIDevice`'s `identifierForVendor` property which returns an `NSUUID` (you can get an `NSString` through the `UUIDString` property on `NSUUID`).

Example:

```
NSString *identifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
```

From the documentation:

> The value of this property is the same for apps that come from the same vendor running on the same device. A different value is returned for apps on the same device that come from different vendors, and for apps on different devices regardless of vendor.

So just run it once on your client's device, fetch their UUID string, and add a check for that same UUID to enable your special debug features.

Comment: It sounds like this isn't scalable in the long run (I have to be physically present if my client gets a new device or if another person needs the same access), but maybe I will use this for the time.

Comment: You could always just add a server component to it, to remove the need to update it with a new app binary. Send the UUID string over to the server to validate whether you should enable debug mode or not.

Comment: Then how would I know whose UUID is whose?

Comment: Well that's up to you. You could have a place in the app where you could view a UUID or send it to you. Have your targeted users do that. Then just register them in a database. The possibilities are up to you.